# R: Plot multiple box plots using columns from data frame

Tags: r, boxplot

I would like to plot an INDIVIDUAL box plot for each unrelated column in a data frame. I thought I was on the right track with `boxplot.matrix` from the `sfsmsic` package, but it seems to do the same as `boxplot(as.matrix(plotdata)` which is to plot everything in a shared boxplot with a shared  scale on the axis. I want (say) 5 individual plots.

I could do this by hand like:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
boxplot(data$var1
boxplot(data$var2)
boxplot(data$var3)
boxplot(data$var4)
```

But there must be a way to use the data frame columns?

EDIT: I used iterations, see my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use the `reshape` package to simplify things

```
data <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100),v2=rnorm(100),v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100))
library(reshape)
meltData <- melt(data)
boxplot(data=meltData, value~variable)
```

or even then use `ggplot2` package to make things nicer

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(meltData, aes(factor(variable), value)) 
p + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")
```

Comment: what is the difference between `melt` and `stack` ?

Answer (score 18):

From `?boxplot` we see that we have the option to pass multiple vectors of data as elements of a list, and we will get multiple boxplots, one for each vector in our list.

So all we need to do is convert the columns of our matrix to a list:

```
m <- matrix(1:25,5,5)
boxplot(x = as.list(as.data.frame(m)))
```

If you really want separate panels each with a single boxplot (although, frankly, I don't see why you would want to do that), I would instead turn to **ggplot** and faceting:

```
m1 <- melt(as.data.frame(m))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(m1,aes(x = variable,y = value)) + facet_wrap(~variable) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Using this still returns a single plot with multiple x categories. I'm trying to make seperate plots for each x category found in a matrix.

`par(mfrow=c(2,5))
boxplot(x = as.list(as.data.frame(plotdata)))` is the code I used, where plotdata is a ...x9 double matrix.

Comment: I want separate plots because they are separate unrelated variables with varying scales. Plotted all together, one dominates the others and you get 8 squashed illegible plots and one big one. I want 9 separate plots which could easily be achieved given the code in my original question. However, I was hoping to speed things up by automating this process by getting R to do a box plot of each variable (column) in a data frame.

Comment: @gisol In that case, if you decide to use ggplot you'll probably want to use `scales = "free_y"` when faceting.

Answer (score 6):

I used iteration to do this. I think perhaps I wasn't clear in the original question. Thanks for the responses none the less.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,5))
for (i in 1:length(plotdata)) {
        boxplot(plotdata[,i], main=names(plotdata[i]), type="l")

}
```