# How to boxplot row-wise matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, boxplot

I have a `matrix` with 8 columns. For each row I'd like to a plot a single boxplot. I prefer the boxplots to be in a single plot. So the following example should produce 4 boxplots (8 values each) - all in a single image.

Data example:

```
> data[2:5,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     
[1,] 0.6  0.5  0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[2,] 0.5  0.5  0.5357143 2.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[3,] 0.5  0.7  0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[4,] 0.5  0.5  1.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
```

So far I've tried:

```
> boxplot(data[2:5,])
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

and this approach from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346880/r-plot-multiple-box-plots-using-columns-from-data-frame):

```
> boxplot(as.list(as.data.frame(data[2:5,])))
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
   'x' must be atomic
```

I've been struggling for ages. Could you please give me hint?

EDIT1:

```
> dput(data[2:5,])
structure(list(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 0.535714285714286, 
    0.535714285714286, 0.518518518518518, 0.518518518518518, 
    0.518518518518518, 0.518518518518518), .Dim = c(4L, 8L))
```

Comment: You might need to post output from `dput (data[2:5,])` since the boxplot function _should_ be able to handle a matrix object without difficulty.

Comment: @42- please take a look at my edit above (the data are slightly different, but structure is still the same)

Comment: Ah. You have a list rather than a matrix.

Comment: @42- oh you're right. I created the matrix in a very wrong way. Could you post it as an answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw boxplots out of matrices, we can use the `boxplot.matrix` function:

```
boxplot.matrix(data, use.cols = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or `boxplot(t(data))`, I believe. +1.

Comment: Neither solution works :-/ it fails with the same error. It's really weird.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use the t() function to transpose that matrix, since R generally does matrix operations on a column basis:

```
nums<-scan(text=" 0.6  0.5  0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
 0.5  0.5  0.5357143 2.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
 0.5  0.7  0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
 0.5  0.5  1.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185")
Read 32 items

 mat<- matrix(nums, nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
 mat
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
[1,]  0.6  0.5 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[2,]  0.5  0.5 0.5357143 2.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[3,]  0.5  0.7 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
[4,]  0.5  0.5 1.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5357143 0.5185185
> boxplot(mat)   # Not correct
> boxplot( t(mat) )
```

[image]

After the edit we now can see that the `data`-object is a rather strange one. It is a list with a dimension attribute so it gets printed as a matrix but it doesn't behave properly when passed to other functions.

Comment: I don't get it - it still fails with the same error on my data. Don't you know why please?