# How do you make a box plot with multiple variables on the same axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to analyze fecundity data among ambient and heat shocked individuals in populations by comparing the number of larvae in brood 1 and brood 2 among the same population. As you can see in the data, the trend tends to be that ambient individuals have more larvae in brood 1 than brood 2 and shocked individuals produce more larvae in brood 2 than in brood 1. I am hoping to show this via a boxplot, but I am open to other suggestions of visualizing the data.

Data

| ID | temp | brood 1 | brood 2 | brood avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sa2 | ambient | 20 | 5 | 12.5 |
| sa2 | ambient | 21 | 10 | 15.5 |
| sa2 | shocked | 19 | 22 | 20.5 |
| sa2 | shocked | 24 | 26 | 25 |
| sa2 | ambient | 20 | 15 | 17.5 |
| sa2 | ambient | 28 | 23 | 25.5 |
| sa2 | shocked | 21 | 31 | 26 |
| sa2 | shocked | 22 | 21 | 21.5 |

I have tried this code:

```r
boxplot(fecundity.df.grouped$brood.1..[ID == "sa2"] ~ fecundity.df.grouped$temperature[ID == "sa2"], 
        fecundity.df.grouped$brood.2..[ID == "sa2"] ~ fecundity.df.grouped$temperature[ID == "sa2"],
        col = c("lightgreen", "darkgreen"), 
        xlab = "temperature treatment",
        ylab = "# of larvae", 
        names = c("brood 1", "brood 2"),
        main = "sa2")
```

When I tried to run this, I got the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
```

I have also tried this ggplot2 code but I cannot get boxplots for both brood 1 and brood 2

```
ggplot(data = fecundity.df.grouped, aes(x = ID, y = brood.1.. , brood.2..)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = temperature), width = 0.8) + theme_bw()
```

Comment: Please share your data.frame or at least a sample of it. I.e. `dput(fecundity.df.grouped)`

Comment: You've sent two formulas to the boxplot call, and no data. The boxplot function is trying to use one of the formulas as data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347017/496803 - pretty much covers your issue I believe - you will need to stack your data first so you have one column with the values to be plotted, and one column that is your grouping variable.